# Crashloopbackoff while creating nginx controller

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I have installed Kubernetes on AWS-EC2 machines, the cluster has a master and 2 nodes connected to it

```
[root@k8-m deployments]# kubectl get nodes
NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
k8-m    Ready    control-plane,master   107m   v1.20.1
k8-n1   Ready    <none>                 101m   v1.20.1
k8-n2   Ready    <none>                 91m    v1.20.1
```

I have a requirement to install ingress controller for exposing the traffic outside and the chosen controller is nginx. Am creating the resources such as **ns, service account, secret, rbac, config map, ap-rbac, daemon-set** config taken from https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress.git.
After creating the properties for ingress controller, am seeing the pods going to crashloopbackoff state

```
[root@k8-m deployments]# kubectl get all -n nginx-ingress
NAME                                 READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx-ingress-555f75f85f-5vxf6   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          11m
pod/nginx-ingress-7wmhw              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          11m
pod/nginx-ingress-mss7v              0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          11m

NAME                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR   AGE
daemonset.apps/nginx-ingress   2         2         0       2            0           <none>          11m

NAME                            READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/nginx-ingress   0/1     1            0           11m

NAME                                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/nginx-ingress-555f75f85f   1         1         0       11m
```

By describing the pod i get the below(pasting only the event details),

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  14m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned nginx-ingress/nginx-ingress-555f75f85f-5vxf6 to k8-n2
  Normal   Pulled     14m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx/nginx-ingress:edge" in 2.456877779s
  Normal   Pulled     14m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx/nginx-ingress:edge" in 2.501405255s
  Normal   Pulled     13m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx/nginx-ingress:edge" in 2.63456627s
  Normal   Created    13m (x4 over 14m)     kubelet            Created container nginx-ingress
  Normal   Started    13m (x4 over 14m)     kubelet            Started container nginx-ingress
  Normal   Pulled     13m                   kubelet            Successfully pulled image "nginx/nginx-ingress:edge" in 2.659821346s
  Normal   Pulling    12m (x5 over 14m)     kubelet            Pulling image "nginx/nginx-ingress:edge"
  Warning  BackOff    3m53s (x47 over 14m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

Am not able to see the logs though

Below are the executions while creating the nginx controller,

```
kubectl create -f common/ns-and-sa.yaml
kubectl create -f rbac/rbac.yaml
kubectl create -f rbac/ap-rbac.yaml
kubectl create -f common/default-server-secret.yaml
kubectl create -f common/nginx-config.yaml
kubectl create -f deployment/nginx-ingress.yaml
kubectl create -f daemon-set/nginx-ingress.yaml
```

Could anyone here advice me on this

Comment: Do you have the logs for the nginx ingress pods?

Comment: Btw, its sorted, i forgot to add the ingress-class while at installing ingress controller